# Divs not removing floats - CSS

Tags: html, css

I am working on a web site.

On `min-width: 769px` and max width of `1203px` I was trying to remove the float for two divs so I can make it a full width option for both divs is:

Since I am using a page builder I tried to use my inspector tool on Chrome and search for appropriate classes or div that can do the trick and I pull the ff codes:

```
@media (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 1203px){
    .pbuilder_column_inner.pbuilder_droppable{
   width: 100%;
   display:block;
   float: none;
}
}
```

But for some reason it doesn't do the trick. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: This is work when I try to add `float:none` in inspect element.
where did you put mediaquery..?

Comment: Is that using the same div above?

Comment: Cache issues? You are using wordpress...cannot see your css in inspect ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi just remove width: 50% in or replace it with 100% instead:

```
.pbuilder_column.pbuilder_column-1-2{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following CSS properties:

```
float:none;
width:100%;
```

on the divs which classes are `pbuilder_column pbuilder_column-1-2` (in the hierarchy, they are right below `pbuilder_row_colwrapper` ).

So, the code would be:

```
@media (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 1203px){
    .pbuilder_column{
        float:none;
        width:100%;
    }
}
```

It does the trick, from my inspector at least.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the class `.pbuilder_column` instead of `.pbuilder_column_inner.pbuilder_droppable`.

Answer (score 0):

```
body,
#pbtheme_wrapper{
  overflow-y: visible !important;
}
.pbuilder_column.pbuilder_column-1-2{
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add below css:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 1203px){
  .pbuilder_row_colwrapper .pbuilder_column {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To me the real problem comes from the way you add your paddings to your elements. By removing or adjusting a lot of them, I was able to achieve it and increase the responsiveness (try to play around margin more than padding in some situations)

The main thing here, is not that your field aren't taking 100% of the container space, it's your button that overflows the container because of a 170px padding (with a !important, which is something I really don't recommend) so it seems like divs aren't taking the right amount of space.